# Call parameterized constructor with AddNew()

Tags: c#, .net, bindinglist

I have `DataGridView` binded on collection of some objects. In `DataGridView`, there's one `ComboBox` with list of names, I'm trying to add new object to collection on every selection.
But problem is that `AddNew()` always call default constructor of child. :/
Here's a code:

```
public class Parent:BindingList<Child>

public Child ChildProperty{get;set;}

public new object AddNew()
    {
        return ChildProperty;
    }

public new void AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildProperty = new Child(this);
        e.NewObject = ChildProperty;
    }
```

I must use parameterized constructor, because i need to pass parent to child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the `new` keyword, you aren't overriding the base class' methods; instead, you're creating brand new methods in the derived class only, which are never called.

Instead, you should **override** the `AddNewCore()` method and return a new object.

**EDIT**: You also need to `Add()` the new instance to the collection in your override.

Comment: Thank yo so much for fast answer! 
Overriden AddNewCore() gives meexception "Data out of range...".
Is AddingNew() fine?

Comment: What is the exact message and stack trace?

Comment: "The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 0 does not have a value. 
at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
at
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)
"

Comment: Made it work! It just works with AddNewCore(). Tnx alot for your effort!